# AnglularJS: Can Protractor run on Windows?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

The angular doc recommends Protractor for e2etesting.
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing

I didn't find any doc about running it on Windows.
Can Protractor run on Windows?

**
Update:

I have some experience on Selenium using C# code to call functions in some selenium dlls to control IE brower.

But what are the relationship between Protractor, Selenium and NodeJS?
Is Protractor an tool(exe) or a lib(dll) or a JS lib(like Jasmine)?

Comment: To answer your update. Protractor is a tool, a program, but not an exe. It is written in javascript but if installing it with `npm install -g protractor` you can run it rom the command line with `protractor` This is what nodejs is for. You run protractor in nodejs. Selenium is the server that starts and communicates with the browsers that protractor in turn sends commands to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run it on windows.

I hope this guide will help you:
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/practical-protractor.html

You should Start Selenium local server and use this basic configuration for run protractor (Depending routes):

```
chromeDriver: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
specs: ['test/e2e/**/*_spec.js'],
chromeOnly: true,
chromeDriver: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
seleniumAddress: 'http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub'
```

Comment: Thanks. I read the guide but it does not mention how to install Protactor on Windows.

Comment: First install node for windows http://nodejs.org/ ,  
Second open Node command prompt and then follow the guide.
I hope it hepls!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes at least it should. It runs on node and node runs on windows. However sometimes projects have windows issues, the most common cause IMO is hardcoding of `/` etc.. If the library uses node [path](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) and similar os independent apis then all is fine.

I have ran protractor on windows without any issues. But not extensively.

Comment: Can you tell me how to install Protactor on Windows?

Comment: Same as on other systems. First install node, then `npm install -g protractor` https://github.com/angular/protractor#to-run-the-sample-tests

Comment: npm is something you get after installing node. It is the package manager for node. That is how you need to instal protractor. yes, sorry forgot to mention, java is also required, well it's required on the machine you choose to run the selenium server. Most likely on your own machine right now.

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites & Installation:

Prerequisites

```
 Node.js (Latest Version)
```

Download NodeJS
Install NodeJs
To test Node.Js installation properly open command prompt and execute the command.
Java Development Kit(JDK)

Download the JDK
Install JDK from
Installation

Install Protractor Globally

Open the command prompt and type following command to install protractor globally.
npm install -g protractor

This will install two command line tools, protractor and webdriver-manager. Try running below command to check protractor version.
protractor –version

The webdriver-manager is a helper tool to easily get an instance of a Selenium Server running. Use it to download the necessary binaries with:
webdriver-manager update

Now start up a server with:
webdriver-manager start